# icefaces-facelets 1.8.2 - Compiler Initialization Error under jboss 4.2

Tags: jboss, facelets, icefaces

When I try to render a page using ifcefaces 1.8.2 with icefaces-facelets 1.8.2 I get enigmatic error:

```
14:27:56:994 ERROR [http-0.0.0.0-8080-2][facelets.compiler] Compiler Initialization Error
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
        at com.sun.facelets.util.Classpath.getAlternativeJarFile(Classpath.java:214)
        at com.sun.facelets.util.Classpath.search(Classpath.java:71)
        at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:428)
        at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:91)
        at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:108)
        at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:218)
        at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:149)
        at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:100)
        at com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DFaceletViewHandler.java:268)
        at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:159)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:19)
        at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2$1.respond(View.java:48)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletRequestResponse.respondWith(ServletRequestResponse.java:201)
        at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2.serve(View.java:77)
        at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:149)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.MultiViewServer.service(MultiViewServer.java:67)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.ServerProxy.service(ServerProxy.java:11)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet$4.service(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:149)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:173)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:534)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:545)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:853)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any idea why is this happening? Application itself deploys cleanly. Runtime is jboss 4.2. Application is simple war with all icefaces libs and dependencies under WEB-INF/libs.

Comment: What was the root cause of this error?